# WPF Binding to behavior property is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, behavior

I have a custom behavior that take a boolean as parameter. I'm trying to bind it to a property in my model but I can't get it to work. (I'm using DevExpress)

```
<dxg:GridControl
        x:Name="dgArticles"
        Grid.Row="1"
        AutoGenerateColumns="None"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Articles, Mode=TwoWay}">

        <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <util:ExpandAllBehavior HasLotPartie="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CahierDesCharges.HasLotPartie }" />
        </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>


    </dxg:GridControl
```

This is a WPF UserControl and the DataContext is defined in code-behind as follow:

```
public partial class GridView : UserControl
{
    public GridView(ArticleViewModel a)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = a;          
    }        
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ArticleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private Cahier cahierDesCharges;
    public Cahier CahierDesCharges { get { return cahierDesCharges; } set { } }

    private ObservableCollection<Article> articles;
    public ObservableCollection<Article> Articles
    {
        get { return articles; }
        set { articles = value; OnPropertyChanged("articles"); }
    }

    public ArticleViewModel() { }

    public ArticleViewModel(Cahier c)
    {
        this.cahierDesCharges = c;
        this.articles = CahierDesCharges.Articles;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

And the CahierDesCharges Class:

```
 public class Cahier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool HasLotPartie { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Article> articles;
    public ObservableCollection<Article> Articles
    {
        get { return articles; }
        set { articles = value; OnPropertyChanged("articles"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Cahier() { }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        Console.WriteLine(propertyName);
    }
}
```

The Behavior:

```
public class ExpandAllBehavior : Behavior<GridControl>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasLotPartieProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HasLotPartie", typeof(Boolean), typeof(ExpandAllBehavior));
    public bool HasLotPartie
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasLotPartieProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasLotPartieProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (HasLotPartie)
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            this.AssociatedObject.CustomRowFilter += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
        }

    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int dataRowCount = AssociatedObject.VisibleRowCount;
        for (int rowHandle = 0; rowHandle < dataRowCount; rowHandle++)
            AssociatedObject.ExpandMasterRow(rowHandle);


    }



    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

I have used the line `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CahierDesCharges.HasLotPartie }"` at a different place and I know it's working. In the following example it's working perfectly fine:

```
 <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView
                AllowScrollAnimation="True"
                EnableImmediatePosting="True"
                IsDetailButtonVisibleBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.CahierDesCharges.HasLotPartie }"
                Name="view"
                ShowGroupedColumns="False"
                ShowGroupPanel="False"
                UseLightweightTemplates="None" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
```

The behavior works fine if I manually set the value to true: `<util:ExpandAllBehavior HasLotPartie="True" />` So I thought that it might be that the DadaContext is not inherited and I use the trick explain by Thomas Levesque on his blog [here](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) and this is what I got:

```
<dxg:GridControl.Resources>             
            <util:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Resources>
        <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <util:ExpandAllBehavior HasLotPartie="{Binding Data.CahierDesCharges.HasLotPartie, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
        </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I've used this trick several time and I know it works too but not in this scenario. Right now I'm stuck with this after several hours of searching so any help is very welcome.

Thank you

Comment: I dont know for sure, but maybe 'HasLotPartie' is always False?
What I mean is try in the Behavior to do your check and register the event on the Loaded of the AssociatedObject.
Maybe when its in the OnAttached, the Binding doesnt resolve yet the current value.

Comment: Using a BindingProxy should work. How do you know that it doesn't?

Comment: @Mishka I've check with the debugger that 'HasLotPartie' in my model is set to true but the binding is not working so the behavior takes the default value of a boolean which is false. I tried to register the event on AssociatedObject.Loaded but no luck there.

Comment: @mm8 I'm pretty sure it should work too but somehow it doesn't. I believe I'm missing something but I can't figure what it is. Using the debugger I checked the value of 'HasLotPartie' in the behavior class and in my model. When it's set to true in the model it still take the default value in the behavior. If I do `<util:ExpandAllBehavior HasLotPartie="True" />` it works fine so I believe my binding is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured that my `CahierDesCharges` was null when the behavior was called. Therefore `HasLotPartie` was false no matter what and so it did not reach my event. So I just moved my if() in `AssociatedObject_Loaded` method and it worked. I needed to wait until the GridControl was fully loaded so the CahierDesCharges wasn't null anymore.
This is my behavior class now:

```
public class ExpandAllBehavior : Behavior<GridControl>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasLotPartieProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("HasLotPartie", typeof(bool), typeof(ExpandAllBehavior));

    public bool HasLotPartie
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasLotPartieProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasLotPartieProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded; //Apllied after GridControl is fully loaded.
        this.AssociatedObject.CustomRowFilter += AssociatedObject_Loaded; //Applied after filtering on Rows
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HasLotPartie)
        {
            int dataRowCount = AssociatedObject.VisibleRowCount;
            for (int rowHandle = 0; rowHandle < dataRowCount; rowHandle++)
                AssociatedObject.ExpandMasterRow(rowHandle);
        }
    }



    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

Now my MasterDetails are always expanded when `HasLotPartie` is true which was the wanted effect.
As always I was stuck focussing on complicated stuff while the solution was easy.